# Is it possible to open a modal automatically when the user has logged in using php or jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to automatically open a modal when a user is logged in using php or jQuery. I am not using a framework.

I have tried using a header to link to the modal but that did not work.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
header('Location:modal.php');
 }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please share what you have tried and the issues you're having and we'll try to help.

Comment: if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {header('Location:modal.php');}

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible via jQuery. You just need to trigger a link that's target is the modal.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a#modal-link').trigger('click');
});
```

And you'd obviously have your modal:

```
<a id="modal-link" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" style="display:none;">Launch Modal</a>


<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
    ....all the modal contents.
</div>
```

---

<sup>*This is to be used on the page where the user that's logged in can view it. How you do that (presumably through PHP/Sessions) is up to you.*</sup>

**Note:** This is how you'd trigger it using [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com).

### [Example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/820wuwqg/)